# Mongoose $or condition for nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

There are my schemas

```
//ProjectModel
const ProjectSchema: Schema = new Schema(
 owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
 users: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ProjectUser", unique: true }]
);

//Project User model
const ProjectUserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", require: true },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: 'basic',
      enum: ["basic", "projectuser", "moderator", "admin"]
    },
    project: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Project", require: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    usePushEach: true,
  }
);
```

The **User** model has common fields like password, name, etc.

I want to find **User** of a **ProjectModel** either among the **owner (UserSchema)** or among **users (ProjectUserSchema)**

```
ProjectModel.findOne()
                    .or([{ owner: req.params.user }, { "users.user": req.params.user }])
                    .then(project => {
                        res.json(project);
                    });
```

But it returns null. And condition `.or([{ owner: req.params.user }, { "users._id": "PROJECT USER ID" }])` doesn't work either.

What should I do?

Comment: Hi AIT. Please post some documents from `ProjectSchema` / `projects` collection. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the incoming `req.params.user` from string to `ObjectId`. Try this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const getProjectByUser = (req, res) => {
  let userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.user);

  ProjectModel
    .findOne({
      $or: [
        { "owner": userId },
        { "users": userId }
      ]
    })
    .then(project => {
      res.json(project);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.json({ error: "Error!" });
    });
}
```

Comment: Should be "users.user"

Comment: Why? it is not  nested object as seen in the `ProjectSchema`.

Comment: `owner` is type `User` and `users` is type `ProjectUser`. `ProjectUser` contains the `user` field of type `User`

Comment: I believe `users` array inside `ProjectSchema` will be an array of `ObjectId`s. Check here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: yes but it is not an array of `User` but `ProjectUser` which have the field: `user`, `role` & `project`. It can have the structure `users[0].role`, `users[0].user`, ...

Comment: Ok. Lets wait for OP to respond.